# updating a value in a multi index data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

could someone please explain this behavior to me?
this is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'key1' : ['f1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f2', 'f3'],
    'key2' : ['fm1', 'fm2', 'fm1', 'fm2', 'fm1'],

    'k' : np.random.rand(5),
    'c' : [100, 200, 100, 150, 400],
    })
df.set_index(["key1","key2"],inplace=True)
```

when I try to change a value:

```
df.loc["f1","fm1"].loc["k"]=-999
```

nothing happens. and `df.loc["f1","fm1"].loc["k"]` still gives the old value
I am wondering  what I am doing wrong, and how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tuple and only one `loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[("f1", "fm1"), "k"] = -999
>>> df
                    k    c
key1 key2                 
f1   fm1  -999.000000  100
     fm2     0.082072  200
f2   fm1     0.119572  100
     fm2     0.752586  150
f3   fm1     0.947604  400
>>>
```

The reason your code doesn't work, is because `df.loc["f1", "fm1"]` references to an object that has no interference with the original `df`, it returns a completely new dataframe and replaces the `k` value, but it doesn't replace it in `df` as well.

Read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) on the pandas documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to change the value on a copy of a slice from the dataframe.
Read about it here: [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

The desired result can be achieved using below code instead:

```
df["k"].loc["f1", "fm1"] = -999
```